# Android alarm screen override

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

Is it possible to override the standard alarm screen of android?
The standard alarm screen I mean is the one which is fired when your alarm goes off.
I want to give it a white background for example. 
If it is not possible, is it somehow possible to fire you own alarm screen while your phone is locked?

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: I cannot find anything to try since I cannot find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> standard alarm screen of android

There's no "standard alarm screen". It's alarm app's screen. Can be any alarm app user uses (also built-in apps differ depending on device vendor).

Comment: Allright then I guess the best way to go is build my own alarm. Thanks